# Prevent redirecting to the control panel from a URI of "/login" when logged in

Tags: control-panel, redirect

I have a top level page that needs the URL of "/login/". It has nothing to do with an actual Craft login.

If I have a logged-in session, that url redirects me to the dashboard (via `UsersController->actionLogin`).

If I'm logged out, the page renders fine.

I thought setting `craft.config.loginPath` to something other than `"login"` would fix it, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug in the latest build of Craft (2.1.2570).  The fix for this will be in Tuesday's (09/02/2014) release.

**UPDATE**

This bug has been fixed in Craft 2.2. http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2579